# Conan, fetch 3rd party libraries compiled for macOS both M1 and Intel architectures

Tags: c++, conan

I'm using Conan in my cmake-based project to upload some 3rd party libraries for macOS.

for example :

`conan_cmake_configure(REQUIRES boost/1.76.0 GENERATORS cmake_find_package)`

Those libraries are compiled by default with the same architecture as my current machine. this means that if I compile in M1 machine, I get the 3rdParty library compiled for arm64
and if I compile in Intel machine, I get the 3rdParty library compiled for x86_64.

I'd like to be able to compile my project for both platforms on a single machine which are ARM64 and x86, using FAT formatted files.

Is there any cmake setting for conan that tell it to get both versions ? or maybe FAT format that contains both versions on the same file ?